# Android - Helper class listener is null

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Single-Activity Fragment architecture in my app with Firestore. I have a Helper class as a Singleton. It fetches all the information from the Firestore collection and uses a listener to call back to the MainActivity, which in turn passes that data to the Fragment for its Adapter. For some reason, my listener in my Helper method for Firebase is null, even though I have implemented it and its methods in my MainActivity. Any suggestions on why this could be happening?

FirestoreHelper class:

```
    public static FirestoreHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance != null) {
            return instance;
        } else {
            instance = new FirestoreHelper();
            if (context instanceof FirestoreHelper.OnDataUpdated) {
                mListener = (OnDataUpdated) context;
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public interface OnDataUpdated {
        void onUserUpdated(UserActivityModel userActivityModel);
        void onAllFoodItemsUpdated(ArrayList<Food> foodItems);
    }
```

MainActivity that implements method and passes data along:

```
    @Override
    public void onAllFoodItemsUpdated(ArrayList<Food> foodItems) {
        foodFragment.resetRecyclerView(foodItems);
    }
```

MainActivity in onCreate that initalizes the FirebaseHelper with context of activity:

```
        FirestoreHelper.getInstance(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the context variable is not instance of your OnDataUpdated interface. So, the code inside 'if' statement won't execute.